# На SGS3 Android 4.12 не работает BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, headset

Нужно написать приложение, которое перехватывает нажатия кнопок наушников. На HTC c Android 4.03 работает, а на SGS3 c Android 4.12 при нажатии на кнопку запускается музыка.

*receiver*:

```
public class BCreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            //do smth
            this.abortBroadcast();
        }
    } 
}
```

Выдержка из *Mainactivity.oncreate()*:

```
BCreceiver receiver = new BCreceiver();
filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
filter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

*manifest*:

```
<receiver android:name=".BCreceiver" android:enabled="true">         
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000000000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="com.example.MOJE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Почему не работает на SGS3?